# Return elements of array in subset sum problem

Tags: python, numpy, dynamic-programming

For the following recursive solution to the subset sum problem ([see this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/subset-sum-problem-dp-25/)), the following code returns true if there is any subset in `a` whose sum equals the value of `sum`

```
def isSubsetSum(set,n, sum) : 

    # Base Cases 
    if (sum == 0) : 
        return True
    if (n == 0 and sum != 0) : 
        return False

    # If last element is greater than sum, then ignore it 
    if (set[n - 1] > sum) : 
        return isSubsetSum(set, n - 1, sum); 

    # else, check if sum can be obtained by any of the following 
    # (a) including the last element 
    # (b) excluding the last element    
    return isSubsetSum(set, n-1, sum) or isSubsetSum(set, n-1, sum-set[n-1]) 

set = [2, 1, 14, 12, 15, 2] 
sum = 9
n = len(set) 
if (isSubsetSum(set, n, sum) == True) : 
    print("Found a subset with given sum") 
else : 
    print("No subset with given sum")
```

How could I also return the indices of `a` which satisfy the `sum`?

Also, how can I make the function work for negative integers in array `a`.

Answer (score 2):

This is one possibility:

```
def isSubsetSum(numbers, n, x, indices):
    # Base Cases
    if (x == 0):
        return True
    if (n == 0 and x != 0):
        return False
    # If last element is greater than x, then ignore it
    if (numbers[n - 1] > x):
        return isSubsetSum(numbers, n - 1, x, indices)
    # else, check if x can be obtained by any of the following
    # (a) including the last element
    found = isSubsetSum(numbers, n - 1, x, indices)
    if found: return True
    # (b) excluding the last element
    indices.insert(0, n - 1)
    found = isSubsetSum(numbers, n - 1, x - numbers[n - 1], indices)
    if not found: indices.pop(0)
    return found

numbers = [2, 1, 4, 12, 15, 3]
x = 9
n = len(numbers)
indices = []
found = isSubsetSum(numbers, n, x, indices)
print(found)
# True
print(indices)
# [0, 2, 5]
```

EDIT: For a cleaner interface, you can wrap the previous function in another one that returns the list of indices on success and `None` otherwise:

```
def isSubsetSum(numbers, x):
    indices = []
    found = _isSubsetSum_rec(numbers, len(numbers), x, indices)
    return indices if found else None

def _isSubsetSum_rec(numbers, n, x, indices):
    # Previous function
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach: Instead of `True` and `False` we return the subarray if found, else `None`:

```
def isSubsetSum(sset,n, ssum) : 

    # Base Cases 
    if (ssum == 0) : 
        return []
    # not found
    if (n == 0 and ssum != 0) : 
        return None

    # If last element is greater than sum, then ignore it 
    if (sset[n - 1] > ssum) : 
        return isSubsetSum(sset, n - 1, ssum); 

    # else, check if sum can be obtained by any of the following 
    # (a) including the last element 
    # (b) excluding the last element    
    a1 = isSubsetSum(sset, n-1, ssum)

    # (b) excluding last element fails
    if a1 is None:
        a2 = isSubsetSum(sset, n-1, ssum-sset[n-1])

        # (a) including last element fails
        if a2 is None:
            return None

        # (a) including last element successes
        else: return a2 + [sset[n-1]]
    else:
        return a1


sset = [2, 1, 4, 12, 15, 2] 
ssum = 9
n = len(sset) 
subset = isSubsetSum(sset, n, ssum) 
if subset is not None : 
    print(subset) 
else : 
    print("No subset with given sum") 

# [2, 1, 4, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

The "easy" way is to make the index list another parameter to the function.  Maintain it as you move down the call tree.

The "clean" way is to build it as you return *back* up the tree with a successful result.  Instead of returning a Boolean, return a list of the indices; `None` indicates failure.

One important note: do *not* "shadow" a built-in type with a variable name; `set` is both dangerous as a variable name *and* misleading.  Try `coins`, for example.

Base cases:

```
if (sum == 0) : 
    return [n]
if (n == 0 and sum != 0) : 
    return None
```

Recursion:

```
include = isSubsetSum(coins, n-1, sum-coins[n-1]):
if include:
    return include.append(n-1)
```

Those are immediate additions for your existing code.  I strongly recommend that you research this problem on line to see how others have solved it.  You waste space and time by passing the entire list and a pointer as parameters; rather, you can start with the last element and work your way back, snipping the end off the list on each call.  This will make your indexing problems much simpler.

Comment: By how much would your suggestion speed up the runtime?

Comment: If you have an addition to your question, please edit the question.
In general, try it and see.  It doesn't change the complexity of the solution, so any change should be negligible.